# Angular reloading same page on authentication

Tags: angular, angularfire2

**Question:** Why would `signInWithEmailAndPassword` reload the same page? I printed the test username and test password which match my firebase test authentication, so I know that the promise is not being processed correctly.

**portal.component.html**

*this is how i collect the data visually from the user.*

```
<input #myUser type="text" value="someone@gmail.com" class="fade-in second" name="login" placeholder="username">
<input #myPass type="text" value="123456" class="fade-in third" name="login" placeholder="password">
<input type="submit" class="fade-in fourth" value="Enter"
 (click)="login(myUser.value,myPass.value)">
```

**portal.component.ts**

*this is where my data is coming from, the username and password are working*

```
@Component
constructor(public afs: FireAuthService) {}
login(user: string, pass: string) {
   this.afs.login(user, pass);
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

*route to use after authenticating*

```
export const mAppRoutes: 
Routes = [...{ path: 'mdashboard', component: MdashboardComponent}...];
@NgModule({
 imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(mAppRoutes)],
 exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

**app.module.module.ts**

*this is the provider for the authentication service*

```
@NgModule
providers: [ FireAuthService ]
```

**fireauthservice.ts**

*i've tried to debug the application both by console and visual alert windows. i noticed that an alert will display before the promise call but not inside or after the call.*

```
@Injectable()
export class FireAuthService {
  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, public router: Router) {  }

  login(user: string, pass: string) {
      console.log(user + ' ' + pass); //will show
      window.alert(user + ' ' + pass); //will show
      this.firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user, pass).then(
          () => {
            console.log(user + ' ' + pass); //will not show
            window.alert(user + ' ' + pass); //will not show
            this.router.navigate(['mdashboard']);
          }
      ).catch(
          (error) => {
            console.log(user + ' ' + pass); //will not show
            window.alert(user + ' ' + pass); //will not show
            window.alert(error.message);
          }
      );
  }
  console.log(user + ' ' + pass); //will not show
  window.alert(user + ' ' + pass); //will not show
}
```

Comment: just try to use `this.router.navigate(['/mdashboard']);`

Comment: hey, using `this.router.navigate(['mdashboard']); does navigate me to the page but it skips the authentication line...

Answer (score 0):

If i didn't missunderstood the question. Your login isn't passing but is not returning an error.

```
this.firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user, pass).then(
              () => {
              //You logic here. if not error but not passing the signing
                this.router.navigate(['mdashboard']);
              }
          ).catch(
              (error) => {
                //if you get an error from the server
                window.alert(error.message);
              }
          );
```

Comment: this is correct, i can do something like window.alert(user + ' ' + pass) right before the this.firebase.auth... . the window.alert will show the correct username and correct password, but once it reaches the this.firebase.auth line it will skip it.

Comment: can you console.log the username and password and put it in your question. Also, please console.log the response you get before the this.router....

Comment: i did the following before the this.firebaseAuth.auth, `console.log(user + ' ' + pass); window.alert(user + ' ' + pass);` and it showed my username and my password, which are someone@gmail.com and 123456, but then i tried it inside the this.firebaseAuth.auth and no dice, it keeps re-loading the page.

Comment: ```() => {
              //You logic here. if not error but not passing the signing
                this.router.navigate(['mdashboard']);
              }```  where you have the ```()``` put ```res=>{console.log(res)}``` and tell me what it prints

Comment: that's the issue, i just tried the res => {console.log(res)} but it will not even reach this line...

Comment: i'm wondering if there's something I did wrong by using a service as a Inject instead of making this a Component ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this, it turns out I had `<input type="submit" ...` which kept causing the reload. From here I changed this to `<input type="button" ...` which fixed the issue.